# insert dynamic images in a crystal reports page from the image folder

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Is there a way to insert images dynamically in a Crystal Reports page from an images folder?

The exact requirement is to display a company's logo at the top of
every crystal report page and when they change, i.e when you have a
new logo , you only change the image(.jpg) in the images folder and
the corresponding image in all the reports should change.

How do I achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm posting the answer i got, hope this would be helpful for others.

```
private void getImage()
    {
        FileStream fs;
        fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "img\\cube.png", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader BinRed = new BinaryReader(fs);
        try
        {
            CreateTable();
            DataRow dr = this.DsImages.Tables["images"].NewRow();
            dr["image"] = BinRed.ReadBytes((int)BinRed.BaseStream.Length);
            this.DsImages.Tables["images"].Rows.Add(dr);

            //FilStr.Close();
            BinRed.Close();

            DynamicImageExample DyImg = new DynamicImageExample();
            DyImg.SetDataSource(this.DsImages);
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = DyImg;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you creating inside CreateTable()? DsImages?

Answer (score 0):

In CR you can do this by: Inserting a placeholder image in your report at the position and size you want it. Right-click on it and select "Format Graphic" -> Go to the "Picture" tab -> Enter a formula in the "Graphic Location" that will return the desired file path.

Comment: Works with CR 2008? I'm putting a image, right-clicking, selecting "Format Object" (there is no Format Graphic)... and there is no "Graphic Location" inside Picture tab. Help me, please.

Comment: @NickeDaSilvaManarin Yes, this is in CR2008. When right-clicking a picture you should not have a "Format Object" option, only "Format Graphic". Make sure you haven't selected multiple objects at once.